# Angular, Не удаётся получить value из FormControl

Tags: typescript, angular

**FormBuilder:**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
...
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { } 
...

this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'email': ['', Validators.required],
  'password': ['', Validators.required],
});
```

**Input:**

```
<my-form-input
    [control]="loginForm?.controls['email']"
    formControlName="email"
    (input)="sendTheNewValue($event)">
</my-form-input>
```

**sendTheNewValue()**

```
sendTheNewValue(){
  console.log(this.loginForm?.controls['email']);
  console.log(this.loginForm?.controls['email'].value);
}
```

`console.log(this.loginForm?.controls['email']);` - выводит в консоль информацию про control, включая value которое обновляется когда обновляю текст в input
Но `console.log(this.loginForm?.controls['email'].value)` - выводит **null**

Что я делаю не так и как мне получить value?

Спасибо!

Comment: @InDevX,
`constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }`
`import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: Обновил вопрос, удалите лишние комментарии, не будем флудить. `this.loginForm?.controls['email'].['value']` так попробуйте

Comment: @InDevX,  ругается на точку между квадратными скобками, попробовал вот так;
`console.log(this.loginForm?.controls['email']['value']);` - ничего не изменилось

Скрин - https://prnt.sc/ZZQUmUv2g9Qt

Comment: какая версия angular? `this.loginForm.value` так попробуйте

Comment: @InDevX `console.log(this.loginForm.get('email').value);`
    `console.log(this.loginForm.get('email'))` - тот же результат.
**UPD**
Если убрать фокус с инпута, а затем опять начать вводить текст - значение **.value** выводиться в консоль, но не будет обновляться пока опять не убрать фокус с инпута

Comment: @InDevX, `console.log(this.loginForm.value);` - вводит email: "", но как только убираю фокус с инпута, а затем опять фокусируюсь на нем и продолжаю ввод - значение email обновляется на то что я ввел в инпут